# Undefined reference to avcodec_alloc_context but ffmpeg linker order correct?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, static-linking, libavcodec, libavformat

I want to build a statically linked executable statically linked to libavcodec and libavformat.
The static ffmpeg library was build with:

```
./configure --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --disable-vaapi 
     --disable-libopus --prefix=myBuild --disable-swresample
```

The linkers are set as follows:

```
g++ -O2 -static -o myBin myBin-myBin.o someotherlibraries.a 
     -L/ffmpeg/myBuild/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil  -lrt -lm -lpthread -lz
```

When compiling, I get ***ONLY ONE*** error message >:-/

```
src/ffmpeg/myProgram.cpp:115: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_alloc_context'
```

Output of  nm /ffmpeg/myBuild/lib/libavcodec.a | grep avcodec_alloc_context :

```
         U avcodec_alloc_context3
         U avcodec_alloc_context3
000003c0 T avcodec_alloc_context3
         U avcodec_alloc_context3
```

I include libavcodec.h with extern "C" {} and I believe my static linker order is correct. Why do I get this error? Is it because this method has been deprecated? How can I solve this?

**SOLUTION:**

Dont use

```
avCtx = avcodec_alloc_context()
```

from maybe older code snippets, but use

```
codec = avcodec_find_decoder(CODEC_ID_XYZ);//for completeness but should be the same as before
avCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec)
```

Comment: What is the output of `nm /ffmpeg/myBuild/lib/libavcodec.a | grep avcodec_alloc_context`?

Comment: I added the output to my post

Comment: @PaoloBonzini does that tell you something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try to call avcodec_alloc_context3 instead?

I encounter no issue calling avcodec_alloc_context3, allocate extradata then call avcodec_open2.

Also the link order should be -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec

Comment: awesome, that worked!! I don't know where I had this old code snippet from. Did they remove the deprecated version at some point?

Comment: Good to know it worked. Perhaps they removed it because they are not interchangeable with newer calls.

Answer (score 2):

if I recall correctly we also had problems with this and the solution was that you have to specifically add the `libavcodec.a` (together with full path) and the other ffmpeg static libraries to the g++ linking step. See if it works this way.

Also, the order of the libraries is important. I don't have the old makefiels anymore, but maybe recall that libavutil should be the first in the list.

So your linking command should be something like:

```
g++ -O2 -static -o myBin myBin-myBin.o someotherlibraries.a 
 /ffmpeg/myBuild/lib/libavutil.a 
 /ffmpeg/myBuild/lib/libavformat.a 
 /ffmpeg/myBuild/lib/libavcodec.a 
  -lrt -lm -lpthread -lz
```

Comment: regarding absolute library paths: isnt your suggested way and -L internally exactly the same? Anyway there was no difference. And the order which I am using seems to be correct in my case. Doesn't the order mean the dependency and they are read backwards?